# Custom Python Package Install getting "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Exceeded 30 redirects."

Tags: python, pip, package, bitbucket, setuptools

I'm trying to create a private python package that can be used across several business projects.  However, to start with something simple, I'm following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-your-custom-python-package-that-you-can-pip-install-from-your-git-repository-f90465867893).  It seems straightforward, but I'm getting an error.  I've pushed the sample package code (toolbox) to my BitBucket repo.  Then, on my Mac's command terminal, I navigated to my `(base)` python (miniconda) environment and tried to install the package like this:

```sh
pip install https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/myteam/toolbox.git
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Normally when I pull code from this BitBucket account I need to either do it with an SSH key or use a password.  Is this error related to that?

Regardless, how can I get this custom private package to download/install from BitBucket without this error?

Comment: `pip install git+https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/myteam/toolbox.git` See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/

Comment: phd, you're right.  I just left out the `git+` in the command.  Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myteam/toolkit.git` if you want to use SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a formalized version of the comments below the question.  You forgot to include the `git+` in the `pip install` command.  If you want to use HTTP use a command like:

```
pip install git+https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/myteam/toolbox.git
```

If you want to use SSH use a command like

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myteam/toolkit.git
```

See supporting documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/)